# Как найти с помощью цикла for самый маленький элемент в массиве,который одновременно делится без остатка на 7 и на 4?

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сделать таким способом,но не получается. Знаю как найти миним. элем и как найти элементы,которые делятся на 7 и 4 без остатка, но по отдельности. А вот как найти минимальное число из тех,что делятся на 7 и на 4 одновременно не могу допереть.

Comment: Код надо текстом, не скриншотом

Comment: Сначала отсортируй массив (например, посредством `Arrays.sort`), а затем ищи в нем первый элемент (с левого краю), который делится на `28` (28 == 7*4) без остатка. Либо нужно обходить весь массив и запомнить самый минимальный.

Answer (score 3):

Вся проблема изначально в `int minElem = array[0]`. Не факт, что этот первый елемент будет делиться на 7 и на 4, но будет меньшим за 28 *(пример: первый елемент 2, но он не делиться ни на 7, ни на 4, но меньше 28)*.

Поэтому и не будет меняться минимальное значение. Измените его на `Interger.MAX_VALUE`.

```
int[] array = {2, 56, 14, 28};
int minE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 28 == 0 && array[i] < minE) {
        minE = array[i];
    }
}

System.out.println(minE); // 28
```